# when trying to access my website it shows access Forbidden

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

i have 10 domains website running on my multishare hosting but when i am trying to accessing my main website it shows me below error

> Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /wp-content/deleteme.389dafd758b849f794dc042743aaa82e.php on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

visit this link to see the error http://www.aaratechinc.com/

Answer (score 0):

Open /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
Look for the line that says

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and change it to

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then enter command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart the apache server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For CentOS

[Setting virtual hosts configuration](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7)

Comment: Which linux distribution is installed on your server?

Comment: i use godaddy hosting provider and i dont know which linux distribution they use in hosting server.

Comment: Try this path  /etc/httpd/sites-available/000-default.conf

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7

Comment: i have only three files in etc folder name 1. aaratechinc.com(empty file), cacheid(file), ftpquota(file)

Comment: Then I think you should contact godaddy hosting support and raise a ticket over there. You must not be having root privileges to view the operating system files.